# Election announcement down?

Tags: feature-request, election

Why is announcement (*Please participate in the...*) still up on meta, but down on main site? I think it should stay up for all duration of nominaiton phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They time out after a max of 2 days - I renewed it.

Comment: On the other sites it was allowed to lapse and then renewed 48 hours before nominations closed. The same applied to the messages for the later phases too.